# catch all changes inside form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jQuery selector function which fires when an element inside a form called `#frmEditWebshop` has changed.
I use:

```
$('#frmEditWebshop').on('change', function() {
```

This works fine for all elements where I change the value with the keyboard and I click out the element.

But I also have text input elements where the value changes by jQuery/Bootstrap plugins like `colorpickers`, `modals`, etc.

These elements don't fire the function.
How can I achieve this without making selectors for each jQuery plugin.

Comment: The first answer.. you can't. You need to implement `change` event to each of them - usually it's not a problem because the plugins have `callback` function to each change. The second answer, you can do this only (I think) with frameworks like `AngularJS` etc.

Comment: Okay thanks I was afraid that I had to set this for every plugin. I couldn't make it work with change, keyup, oninput, etc. Mabey someone else knows a good solution, for now I will set this per plugins callback function.